# Facebook SDK use Graph API version 1.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

There are some differences between the Facebook graph API versions 1.0 and 2.0 that I'm not so fond of so I would like to downgrade to the graph API version 1.0.

Any ideas how to do this?

Here's the code I'm using right now, which makes a call to version 2.0:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/friends"
                             parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"20", @"limit", nil]
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                          if (!error) {
                              // Sucess! Include your code to handle the results here
                              NSLog(@"***** user friends with params: %@", result);
                          } else {
                              // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                          }
                      }];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be accomplished at the `FBRequest` level.

You need to create the FBRequest yourself and use `overrideVersionPartWith:`.

Keep in mind this will only work if your Facebook app was created before the v2.0 API was released. Newer apps are blocked from using the old API at all.

It will look something like this:

```
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"/me/friends"
                                          parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"20", @"limit", nil]
                                          HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request overrideVersionPartWith:@"v1.0"];

[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                          if (!error) {
                              // Success! Include your code to handle the results here
                              NSLog(@"***** user friends with params: %@", result);
                          } else {
                              // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                          }
                      }];
```

Answer (score 7):

while the above answer is correct you can use

```
[FBSettings enablePlatformCompatibility: YES];
```

And all FbRequests target api v1.0 here is the official documentation about this:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSettings/

And if you want to target individual request that use of v1.0 of graph api you can specify it like this:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"v1.0/me/friends"
                         parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"20", @"limit", nil]
                         HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                  completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                      if (!error) {
                          // Sucess! Include your code to handle the results here
                          NSLog(@"***** user friends with params: %@", result);
                      } else {
                          // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                      }
                  }];
```

And here is the official docs that explains this
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBRequest/

See overrideVersionPartWith: method and **Discussion** of it

Comment: This is definitely a better solution than just overriding the version for an individual call. Not sure how I missed that when reading the docs.

Comment: when making a /v1.0/{id} call I get a "Unknown path components : /{id}" error - any idea what's going on?

Comment: @EugeneMi 
check the "paging"/"next" value you get from the result of first query , if you usually replace h-t-t-p-:-//graph... with @"", you now need to also remove the v1.0 or v2.0 string that left there

Comment: Sorry man, but `[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"v1.0/me/friends" ...]` won't work. It will never overwrite API version (at least with the current Facebook SDK 3.20). Two other ways will work: `[FBSettings enablePlatformCompatibility: YES]` and `[request overrideVersionPartWith:@"v1.0"]`